# Create on click hyperlink event in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a gridview with and edit and delete hyperlink in one column. My question is how do I generate a method in my codebehind so that when I click the hyperlink, it will call the method? Right now it takes me to the page, but I want to be able to modify date before loading the page. For example, when I click the button control in design mode, it generates the method. How can I do something similar for hyperlinks in this case?

Here's what I have:

```
              <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="EditLink" runat="server" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/EditCustomer.aspx" 
                        Text='Edit'>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="DeleteLink2" runat="server" 
                        NavigateUrl="~/DeleteCustomer.aspx" 
                        Text='Delete'>
                        </asp:HyperLink>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

**Edit**
It must be a Hyperlink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the code-behind that you want to execute is on the destination page. If it is some initialization code that depends on a value in the GridView, you can append it as a parameter to the URL. For example, if the GridView has a "LastDate" field:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="EditLink" runat="server" Text="Edit"
            NavigateUrl='<%# "~/EditCustomer.aspx?Date=" & Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"LastDate") %>' />
        ...
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then you can retrieve the parameter in the destination page and use it as you want to initialize the page before showing it:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        If Not IsNothing(Request.QueryString("Date")) Then
            InitPageWithDate(CDate(Request.QueryString("Date")))
            ...
        End If
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I wanted. I'll give it a shot when I get back to work.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a buttonfield and gridview event RowCommand

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Preview" Text="link1" ButtonType="Link" />
```

or a templatefield and gridview event RowCommand

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnAccept" runat="server" CommandName="Preview"></asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind in the RowCommand

```
if (e.CommandName == "Preview")
{
   int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
   GridViewRow row = grvAcceptRejectRootCause.Rows[index];
   string lblAction = ((Label)row.FindControl("lblAction ")).Text;
   string txtRootCause = ((TextBox)row.FindControl("txtRootCause")).Text;    
}
```

Comment: Apparently a linkbutton uses an extra server requests. For this reason I'm trying to figure out how to use a similar function you layed out abovec except with a hyperlink.